# Visual Studio Ignored breakpoints in a single file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

**Prelude:**

as a developer 'living in' VS for decades, never thought I would be creating a post on StackOverflow regarding such matter, yet.. here it goes.

**Problem:**

In a single CPP file, breakpoints wouldn't be hit.

**Already Tried:**

- rebuilding
- cleaning
- removing .VS folder
- rebooting
- editing and saving the problematic CPP file

**Current State:**

VS still complains that the source file and one compiled are different.

Ideas?

Comment: The output window shows which symbols are loaded. Are symbols being loaded for your module? Is your project configured to output symbols (make sure you're in Debug mode would be a good start)

Comment: symbols are loaded.. it happens for a specific version of the CPP file. For versions prior to a certain revision all is fine (brains out(. I can switchin between revisions of the cpp file, and debugging works (meaning PDB files are rebuilt and loaded) but once I switch to to two most recent revisions I cannot debug. Sounds crazy but that's how it is.

Comment: You say that your symbols are loaded and that it has something to do with the version of your CPP file. I'm guessing that Visual Studio gets some identifier of your CPP file from the symbols and verifies that same identifier of your CPP file from the CPP file itself and compares those. Do you have any idea what identifier it is and how you might retrieve this, not only from the CPP file, but also from the symbols file?

Comment: I've just updated VS from 16.11.10 to 16.11.11 and it shouted at me with '
Error C1853 'file.pch' precompiled header file is from a different version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa) file..cpp 1 
" Note: file.cpp is the problematic file.. guess that's normal.. the version changed..

Answer (score -1):

Ok, while I have no slightest clue, what's been going on over here and the 'solution' seems as 'crazy' as the 'problem' at hand, what worked for me was to update to a revision few slots back in time and... ***to copy over contents of the most recent revision through notepad...***

**Don't ask me why. I have no idea.**

Why this would work and not when directly updating to most recent revision of the file through subversion.. also why now I can edit the file rebuild and debugging works.. like nothing happened.

**The most interesting part? Same behavior on other workstations.**

The only logical explanation I can come up with, so far, is that somehow, recent revisions of the file ended up containing some sequence of (non-printable?) characters that resulted in checksum of the file being computed wrong by the debugger.

That could explain why I kept having trouble even after rebuilds and others having same issue on different machines.

Still, that assumes a bug in VS.